# Не работает команда "javac" в консоли

Tags: java, windows

Системные переменные JAVA_HOME,JRE_HOME сделал. Команда "java" работает(работала и до создания переменной).

Comment: JDK-то установлен?

Comment: @Nofate если пути указал, то видимо да.

Comment: javac - это по сути java компилятор. Если он не работает может быть действительно проблема с JDK. А из интегрированной среды разработки у вас компилируется?
И скриншотики прикрепите, а то так - гадание на кофейной гущи получается.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Указать ещё одну системную переменную PATH: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk\bin. Если столкнулись с такой проблемой, то сначала пропишите эту переменную. Если не помогло, то пропишите JAVA_HOME: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk и JRE_HOME: C:\Program Files\Java\jre.

Comment: Это решение вопроса?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте такой вариант
C:\Users>"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin\javac.exe" hello.java
Мне в свое время помогло

Answer (score 0):

Посмотри путь `C:\Program Files\Java\**jre**\bin`, а не такой: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk\bin`.

Значит у тебя русск. среда выполнения для *Java* — минимальная реализация виртуальной машины, необходимая для исполнения *Java*-приложений. Без компилятора и других средств разработки.

Просто нужно установить *JDK*.

Comment: Судя по принятому ответу, jdk было установлено.

Comment: Было установлено ещё два года назад.

Answer (score 0):

Указать ещё одну системную переменную PATH: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk\bin. Если столкнулись с такой проблемой, то сначала пропишите эту переменную. Если не помогло, то пропишите JAVA_HOME: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk и JRE_HOME: C:\Program Files\Java\jre.

Это ПОМОГЛО

Answer (score 0):

Прописал путь, ничего не изменилось, прописал переменные среды, ничего не изменилось, такое уже было у меня раньше - перегрузил комп и все заработало. Возможно хватило бы только прописать путь и перегрузить комп. [Картинка с переменными среды](https://yadi.sk/i/VssSR8l_3aNVay)

Comment: Возможно ли, что после прописания переменной среды вы не перезапустили консоль?

Answer (score 0):

изменить переменную окружения Path в Windows8:
Панель управления ⇒ Система ⇒ расширенные Системные настройки
Переключиться на вкладку "Advanced" ⇒ переменные окружения
В разделе "системные переменные" прокрутите вниз до пункта "PATH" ⇒ изменить

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk\bin после bin поставил `"\"` все заработало `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk\bin\;`